# Parse XML string to JSON

Tags: json, xml

Im trying to parse an XML string to JSON.

Im trying to look for a parser where you can define an element not to be parse and and treat all child element and string inside of it as text.

Here is a sample of my XML string.
http://dpaste.com/2N0TQYX

I want all element and string inside of it not to be parse and treat it as a text.

```
{mrk: {'#text': '<g>Dog</g> is playing on the <g>park</g>' } }
```

instead of

```
mrk: {'#text': ['is playing on the'], 'g': [{'#text': 'Dog'}, {'#text': 'park'}}
```

Comment: I want to declare MRK element not to parse anything inside of it.

Comment: do you want somone to code it for you or you just need converter? you have plenty of converters online

Comment: "Im trying to parse an XML string to JSON." Why? What is your actual end goal? To transform one specific XML format into one specific JSON format? Or just to extract some data from the XML, but you don't know how to traverse the document in your language of choice? What language / framework *are* you using?